# How to Read PDF documents from sever using webview?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, pdf

I have some PDF books over Server,Here is my code to Read these books from sever.

```
self.webView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)] autorelease];
self.webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
self.webView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.webView];
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url.pdf"]]];
```

Using this code nothing appear in webview,but when i add the same book in my resourse folder then its works.Can any one help me how can i fix it using above url ?thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your last line to this :

```
NSString *urlString = @"url.pdf";
NSString *encodedUrl = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedUrl];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

The link of pdf file you provided contains file with thousands of pages,so it might take time to load.

Comment: Check my updated answer.It may work,as url contained whitespaces.Try it.

Comment: Hey check this one...This pdf file is very huge.

Comment: This code will work,you need to add indicator to show the process ,as there are more than 1800 pages in pdf file,so it will take some time.

Comment: i implement the activity indicator but its not stay on same view.its moves to next view where is webview .can u help me that how we can stay on previous untill the book is full open in webview.thanx

Comment: You can use this method to navigate after webview finished loading : 
`- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView`